# Cannot read Wordpress site anymore

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been working on my Wordpress website changing some components in functions.php (email configuration, not the vital components) and all of sudden the website cannot be reached anymore. When I try to open the url I just get a blank page and the following message:

> Fejl ved indlæsning af URI: Could not load the source for
>   http://www.websitename.dk/. [Exception... "Component returned failure
>   code: 0x80470002 (NS_BASE_STREAM_CLOSED) [nsIInputStream.available]" 
>   nsresult: "0x80470002 (NS_BASE_STREAM_CLOSED)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js :: onResponse :: line 607"
>   data: no] Stack:
>   onResponse@resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js:607:25
>   onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:123:17 Line: 607,
>   column: 0

I've read in different blogs that the error `0x80470002` might be related to an upgrade of PHP on the server. I've upgraded and downgraded from PHP 7.2 to 7.3/7.1 and still I cannot access the site. Also tried to clear the cache and reach the site from different devices and browsers. Also didn't work.

Any ideas why I got this error message?

Comment: Check it out - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ssl-pages-blank-after-3-4-2-update/

Comment: Hello Saud please follow below steps one by one. 1. Have you checked your wordpress site's error log? 2. Please enable wp_debug to true in your wp-config.php and try to see the site. If there is any fatal error it will show you there. If above 2 steps doesn't show anything then let me know. I will help you.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi chiku. I cannot access the admin-panel anymore. Also shows a blank page. How do I enable wp_debug in my wp-config.php?

Comment: try deactivating all plugin

Comment: it's not wordpress issue : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/dns_probe_finished_nxdomain-and-%E2%80%A8err_name_not_resolved/